# CentOS 5 installation - GRUB installed on USB drive

Tags: linux, centos, usb, grub

I installed CentOS via unetbootin and USB stick. Unfortunately, I can not now start my system w/o my USB usb drive.

Can someone provide me with some information how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

pull the usb stick out and run

```
# grub-install --recheck '(hd0)'
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.
Installation finished. No error reported.
This is the contents of the device map /boot/grub/device.map.
Check if this is correct or not. If any of the lines is incorrect,
fix it and re-run the script `grub-install'.

(fd0)   /dev/fd0
(hd0)   /dev/sda
```

pick your device and rerun (only if it wasn't recognized as hd0)

```
# grub-install '(hd0)'
Installation finished. No error reported.
This is the contents of the device map /boot/grub/device.map.
Check if this is correct or not. If any of the lines is incorrect,
fix it and re-run the script `grub-install'.

# this device map was generated by anaconda
(hd0)     /dev/sda
```